# Reusing methods in Angular interceports

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor

Lets say I have a method called getUsers and an API Interceptor which handles my token refresh functionality.
Here is the scenario:

- I send a `GET` request using `getUsers` to:

> http://example.com/api/users

- My token is expired so I get a 401 error
- API Interceptor refreshes my token and calls the endpoint again:

> response.config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + response.access_token;
>   $http(response.config);

It works fine, but how do I actually re-use my original method (`getUsers`) instead of just resending `$http` request because I need to modify some data on callback

Answer (score 0):

What really worked in my case is actually intercepting requests, not responses. So basically I have a timestamp of my token creation in my local storage which I compare to current time every time I send an API request. If it's been longer than say 10 hours (*insert your lifespan*) I request a new token.